# Update JSP in running Tomcat for Java extension in VS CODE

Tags: jsp, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm running a webapp in Tomcat and am able to run the server by using

- [Tomcat for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat)
- [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug)

Everything works fine (I can even compile the app via maven to the target folder for production.)

*What I would like to happen is when I edit a JSP in the source, to have it reflected on my localhost without having to stop and restart the server.*

I can manually edit the files in the TARGET folder and have it reflected immediately, but that seems like a bad idea. I could also have a process running to 'watch' the src folder and copy over any change that way.

I think I'm just missing a setting.xml or something somewhere that could help the extension know when a file has changed.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a way to do this? I'm currently looking into doing the same. I got it working with java files but changing jsp files does nothing unless i rebuild my entire project

Comment: no @crimson589 - no, I did not. I still suffer with Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fsdeploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mightycoco.fsdeploy),
I set the workspace settings.json as

```
{
  "fsdeploy.nodes": [
    {
      "source": "/home/swain/workspace/parti/demosx-buttercon/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/site/butter",
      "target": "/home/swain/workspace/parti/demosx-buttercon/target/ROOT/WEB-INF/jsp/site/butter",
      "include": "**/*.*",
      "exclude": "**/min/*.*"
    }
  ],
  "fsdeploy.deployOnSave": true
}
```

to target limited jsp files for css publishing, it works perfect.
BTW, I've been using `mvn sass:watch` to monitor css change.